# Probability, Why is this wrong?

Tags: probability

So we have a deck of 32 cards , let's suppose we take 5 cards at the same time,
then we search for the probability of having at least one ♥ heart card

for this we can do 1- p(having no heart card) which translate to

1 - (24 C 5)/(32 C 5)

which will give you approximately 0.77

so far it's all good,

the problem start here :

we can (or can't?) also consider that "having at least one heart" as : "pick one heart then any other 4 cards"

which translate (or not?) to :

((8 C 1)*(31 C 1))/|Ω|

which give 1.25, which is obviously wrong

The question is, where is the mistake is my process?

Comment: A variant on your second calculation would be $\frac{P(8,1) P(31,4)}{P(32,5)}$, which would be the probability that the *first* selection is a heart. But this is different from the probability that *some* selection was a heart.

Comment: Assuming that the second formula is $(8C1)(31C4)/(32C5)$ that does give the value $5/4$. You are seriously overcounting there. If the hand contains two or more hearts, then those show up twice or more in the tally.

Comment: @Ian That's not quite true. The probability of the first card being a heart is $$\frac{P(8,1)P(31,4)}{P(32,1)P(31,4)}$$ Your denominator is just the number of ways of picking 5 cards, so your numerator and denominator are not counting the same "things."

Comment: @ThomasAndrews These are the same: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=P%2832%2C1%29*P%2831%2C4%29%3D%3DP%2832%2C5%29

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You overcount the hands with more than one heart in the second method.
If the hand contains, for example, both the ace and king of hearts and three non-hearts, such hands are counted twice, because you may have first selected the heart ace as the heart, and the king among the 4 out of remaining 31. Or the other way round. Should a hand contain more than two hearts the overcounting becomes more severe, but those hands are not very numerous.

A correct variant is the following.

Assume that the hand has $k$ hearts and hence $5-k$ non-hearts. The number of such hands is clearly
$$
{}_8C_k\cdot{}_{24}C_{5-k}=\binom 8 k\cdot\binom{24}{5-k}
$$
depending on how you want to write the binomial coefficients.
Thus the number of hands with at least one heart is
$$
\sum_{k=1}^5{}_8C_k\cdot{}_{24}C_{5-k}=158872.
$$
As a reality check we see that the total number of hands is $\binom{32}5=201376$, and the number of hands with no hearts $\binom{24}5=42504=2013776-158872.$

Answer (score 1):

You neglected to mention that there were eight $\heartsuit$ among the 32 cards in the deck.

Now the probability of drawing *at least* one $\heartsuit$ can be calculated by complements $1-P(H=0)$, directly, or by using the Principle of Inclusion and Exclusion.

$$\begin{align}P(H{=}0) & = \dfrac{\dbinom{24}{5}}{\dbinom{32}{4}} \\[2ex] P(H{\geq} 1) & = \dfrac{\dbinom{8}{1}\dbinom{24}{4}+\dbinom{8}{2}\dbinom{24}{3}+\dbinom{8}{3}\dbinom{24}{2}+\dbinom{8}{4}\dbinom{24}{1}+\dbinom{8}{5}}{\dbinom{32}{4}}\\[2ex] P(H{\geq} 1) & = \dfrac{\dbinom{8}{1}\dbinom{31}{4}-\dbinom{8}{2}\dbinom{30}{3}+\dbinom{8}{3}\dbinom{29}{2}-\dbinom{8}{4}\dbinom{28}{1}+\dbinom{8}{5}}{\dbinom{32}{4}}\end{align}$$

You attempted the latter, but only used the first term, which over counts cases where more hearts are drawn.